# Creating DbGeography from a DbGeometry

Tags: .net, sql-server, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps Api for .NET and it gives me a DbGeometry but I need to store the location as a DbGeography in the database. How do I go from a DbGeometry to a DbGeography?

Answer (score 0):

If you've already got it in a database table, you can do something like:

```
select geography::STGeomFromText(cast(yourGeomCol as varchar(max)), 4326)
from yourTable
```